# delete duplicate data which have different date entries keeping the earliest one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has some incorrect data that I want to remove.

The logic is as follows. Where the code, name and source are equal (like the 1st three rows in the table below I want to keep the record with the earliest date, so 2017-01-02 in this case and then remove the other two rows. How to do this?

```
   DateEntry    Code    Name     Source
   2017-01-02   ABCF    Blah     SS
   2017-03-02   ABCF    Blah     SS
   2017-04-02   ABCF    Blah     SS       
   2017-03-08   BVFT    Andy     SS
   2017-04-14   BVFT    Andy     SS
   2017-04-20   BVFT    Blob     SS
   2017-04-28   BVFT    Blob     SS
   2017-05-14   BVFT    Blob     SS
   2017-06-02   BVFT    Blob     SS
```

What I want,

```
   DateEntry    Code    Name     Source
   2017-01-02   ABCF    Blah     SS  
   2017-03-08   BVFT    Andy     SS
   2017-04-20   BVFT    Blob     SS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a row number partitioned by the columns `Code`, `Name` and `Source` and order by ascending order of `DateEntry` column. Then delete the rows which having row number greater than 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by Code, Name, Source
        order by DateEntry    
     ), *
     from your_table_name
)
delete from cte
where rn > 1;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/OVU14324)**

Answer (score 1):

You should `ROW_NUMBER()` function By `SubQuery` Form :

```
SELECT DateEntry,
       Code,
       Name,
       Source
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code,
                                          Name,
                                          Source ORDER BY dateentry) rn
    FROM <table_name>
) a
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Result :**

```
|  DateEntry | Code | Name | Source |
|------------|------|------|--------|
| 2017-01-02 | ABCF | Blah |     SS |
| 2017-03-08 | BVFT | Andy |     SS |
| 2017-04-20 | BVFT | Blob |     SS |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ranking function [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) with `PARTITION BY Code, Name`:

```
WITH Ranked 
AS
(
   SELECT
      DateEntry, Code,Name, Source,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code, Name ORDER BY DateEntry) AS RN
   FROM table1
)
SELECT DateEntry, Code,Name, Source
FROM Ranked
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The ranking function will generate a row number for each row, with the first in the group with 1, the one with the earliest date. Then the filter will remove all except the first row in each group.

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dffa8/3)

Results:

```
|  DateEntry | Code | Name | Source |
|------------|------|------|--------|
| 2017-01-02 | ABCF | Blah |     SS |
| 2017-03-08 | BVFT | Andy |     SS |
| 2017-04-20 | BVFT | Blob |     SS |
```

---

Keep in mind that, this won't actually *delete* the other rows, this is just a select.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DateEntry ORDER BY DateEntry DESC) AS rn
FROM MyTable
) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
;with cte as (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code,Name,Source ORDER BY DateEntry DESC) AS rnum
FROM MyTable
)
delete from cte where rnum>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t1 AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,Name,Source ORDER BY DateEntry) AS   
'Rank',Code,Name,Source 
FROM TABLE
)
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE t1.Rank>1
```